# Send email from Omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, email, google-chrome-os, launcher, launchy

I use Launchy to very easily send one-line emails on my Windows PC.  I just type alt-space, then "wife", tab, then the text of the message.  However, I can't figure out an easy way to do this or the equivalenton my Chromebook.

Is there a way I could compose a one line email with a keyboard combination from the Chrome Omnibox?  I don't want to pull up the gmail page at any point, just send the email immediately.

Answer (score 1):

[Send from Omnibox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-from-omnibox/pfebpahfiklkbdgdacdcdojjejhpbkgc?hl=en-US) is very close to what I was looking for, only it opens the gmail page and requires you to submit the email from there.

> Compose an email without leaving the page.
>
> Compose an email just by typing in Chrome's address bar.
>
> Emails are started with a "." and a space. For example:
>
> . matt@example.com sub What's up?, I thought you'd enjoy this picture:
>   http://bit.ly/6kEfZ0
>
> will open a compose window (using mailto) to matt@example.com with the
>   subject "What's up?" and the included message.
>
> Define a custom shortcut for someone's email by typing
>
> . set m, matt@example.com
>
> and then "m" can always be used instead of matt@example.com.